# How to view/edit M-values of PointZ shapes ArcMap 9.3.1

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3

I realize this is a very basic question, but however I can't find any basic Q&A on something so simple. I added three new points to a shapebatch in ArcMap. By default when I added them, it made the M-Value the equivalent of a minimum double value (-1.79769313486232E+308). I know this because I've written software to read ShapeFiles. For testing purposes I need to be able to change the M-values of these points to see how it handles certain values.

I've tried opening the 'Edit Sketch Properties' windows. It's grayed out and doesn't even contain an M column. All tutorials/guides I've come across pertain to PolyLineZ.

Is the M-value computed on something within the shapefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Shapefile is "M aware" the Shape column will display "Polygon M". Also, the Source tab of the Layer's Properties will read, "Coordinates have measures: yes". I just created a new Shapefile with Measures and was able to edit the M values from the Edit Sketch Properties Window. I had to start an Edit Session, of course. Each Vertex of a Polygon has its own M value.